# How can I set permission for an user in Bonobo Git Server

Tags: git, bonobo

I downloaded the installed the Bonobo Git Server application and created repository and users. Everything is working fine except I am not seeing any option to set the permission to a user. For example I want create an user "user1" with read only permission. Let me know if there is any option to set the permission to an user.

Answer (score 0):

[Bonobo issue 256](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/256) states:

> > Is this possible with Bonobo out of the box or with some additional scripts?
>
> You can either allow anonymous users to have a read only access to the repository or you are giving read/write access to individuals/groups.

([groups with AD: Active Directory, for example](https://bonobogitserver.com/ad-membership/))

However, since [PR 269](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/pull/269), the authenticated user name is accessible via an
environment variable, to allow for git hook validation of the user.
(Bonobo 4.0.0+)

That means the repo can have, on the server side, a pre-receive hook for rejecting a push from that user.